# Selecionar e exibir caractere em mais de uma div

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou trabalhando em um tema para Ghost e na exibição dos artigos (feed do blog) o título do artigo e o resumo será exibido da seguinte maneira:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para isso utilizo o seguinte código:

```js
var getText = $('.title').html();
var sliceText = getText.slice(0, 1);

$(".letter").append(sliceText);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Primeiro Article Card -->
<article class="card-article">
  <header class="card-title">
    <h1 class="title">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h1>
    <div class="letter"></div>
  </header>
</article>

<!-- Segundo Article Card -->
<article class="card-article">
  <header class="card-title">
    <h1 class="title">Sed ac vehicula nulla.</h1>
    <div class="letter"></div>
  </header>
</article>

<!-- Terceiro Article Card -->
<article class="card-article">
  <header class="card-title">
    <h1 class="title">Vivamus ac elit a ex pulvinar.</h1>
    <div class="letter"></div>
  </header>
</article>
```

Basicamente eu pego o primeiro caractere do `<h1 class="title"></h1>` e o exibo na `<div class="letter"></div>`.

O problema é que, embora eu consiga exibir o caractere nas demais divs `.letter` da página, o código captura o caractere apenas do primeiro `<h1 class="title"></h1>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você precisa fazer uma iteração dos elementos. O `$('.title').html();` irá pegar apenas o primeiro elemento com a classe `.title`. Pode usar o `.each` para percorrer todos os elementos `.title` e chegar ao resultado:

```js
$('.title').each(function(){
   
   var getText = $(this).text();
   var sliceText = getText.slice(0, 1);
   
   $(this)  // elemento da vez
   .closest('header') // procura o ancestral com a tag "header"
   .find('.letter') // procura no ancestral acima a classe .letter
   .append(sliceText); // insere a letra
   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Primeiro Article Card -->
<article class="card-article">
  <header class="card-title">
    <h1 class="title">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h1>
    <div class="letter"></div>
  </header>
</article>

<!-- Segundo Article Card -->
<article class="card-article">
  <header class="card-title">
    <h1 class="title">Sed ac vehicula nulla.</h1>
    <div class="letter"></div>
  </header>
</article>

<!-- Terceiro Article Card -->
<article class="card-article">
  <header class="card-title">
    <h1 class="title">Vivamus ac elit a ex pulvinar.</h1>
    <div class="letter"></div>
  </header>
</article>
```

> Note que usei `.text()` em vez de `.html()`. É mais interessante no
>   caso de pegar apenas o texto, e não o HTML do elemento.